# ajax js-php POST request not working, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I couldn't find any deep guide to ajax, especially for a php server side.
I currently try only to post the data to the PHP and test it before trying my luck with dumping to SQL.
Worked on it for 2 days, still not working. Guess it's a good time to head to stock overflow:
html+js:

```js
<script>//send data scripts
        var formNode = document.querySelector("#customerRegiForm");
        var formData = new FormData(formNode);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "php/formSubmission.php", true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
               document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = request.responseTexts;
            }
        };
        request.send(formData);
    </script>
```

```html
<form class="regiForm" id="customerRegiForm" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
        <div>
        Name: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstname" class="" required />
        Family Name: <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastname" class="" required />
        </div>
        <div>
        Email: <input type="email" class="" id="email" name="email "required />
        </div>
        <div>
        Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            Country: <select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId" style="width: 100px">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
            </select>
            State: <select name="state" class="states" id="stateId">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
            </select>
            City: <select name="city" class="cities" id="cityId">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
        Address: <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p id="testing"></p>
```

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: user
 * Date: 17-Sep-16
 * Time: 14:50
 */
echo $_POST['email'];
?>
```

also, any recommendations for videos and books in the subject?

Comment: you have a space inside the email attribute. `<input type="email" class="" id="email" name="email "required />`

See that space before `required`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's just a typo from your real code, but

```
request.responseTexts
```

should be

```
request.responseText
```

(the final "s" is not ok)

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to change in your code, such as:

- Look at the following `<input>` element,

  ```
  <input type="email" class="" id="email" name="email "required />
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  Can you see that extra space after `email`? That's why on the PHP side, `echo $_POST['email'];` won't work. This `<input>` element should be like this:

  ```
  <input type="email" class="" id="email" name="email" required />
  ```
- Look at this JavaScript statement here,

  ```
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = request.responseTexts;
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  It should be,

  ```
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = request.responseText;
  ```
- Look the the top `<form>` element,

  ```
  <form class="regiForm" id="customerRegiForm" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  But I see no `formValidation()` function in your code. Create a function named `formValidation()` and make sure you return `false` from that function, otherwise the form will get submitted each time you hit the submit button. So, your script should be like this:

  ```
  <script>
      function formValidation(){
          var formNode = document.querySelector("#customerRegiForm");
          var formData = new FormData(formNode);
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          request.open("POST", "post.php", true);
          request.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                 document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = request.responseText;
              }
          };
          request.send(formData);
          return false;
      }
  </script>
  ```

Comment: form validation is in part of my code that isn't on display. even when i correct the mistakes it doesn't display anything